# Apache Solr - Update default log4j2.xml file without restarting solr service

Tags: solr, log4j2

I need to update the log4j2.xml file in Solr which is present in the default location "server/resources/log4j2.xml" without restarting the Solr service. Is there a way around to achieve this? This is for a Production environment.

Comment: Did you notice that in Solr UI you have access to logs levels ? This might be what you're looking for. It won't change the log4j2.xml file though.

Comment: This is related to solr log files rotation. I need to increase the roll out value to 20 from the default 10. Is this possible without doing a service restart?

Comment: You'd have to try, it's possible that the server listen for file changes but I don't know if it's configured like this by default.